# Threshold entire dataset and save the thresholded images

Tags: python, opencv

I want to threshold an entire dataset of images using opencv and save the thresholded images in the same directory. How do I do that? I have tried a way(code below) but it shows the following error: TypeError: img is not a numpy array or scalar. 
Any help would be much appreciated

```
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from imutils import paths

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help= "Path to test dataset")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type = int, default = 128,
help = "Threshold value")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

test_path =os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"]])
TestPath = list(paths.list_images(test_path))
idxs = np.arange(0, len(TestPath))
images = []
path_to_save = "C:/Desktop/Python Training/test"

def main():

for i in idxs:
    image = cv2.imread(test_path[i])
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (200, 200))
    image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    images.append(image)

return (np.array(images))

cv2.imwrite(path_to_save, images)
cv2.waitKey(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: You don't really need to write any Python to greyscale, resize and threshold a bunch of images, by the way. You can just use **ImageMagick** at the command line like this `mkdir results; magick mogrify -colorspace gray -resize 200x200! -threshold 50% -path results *.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the os module, I have used the glob module and applied minor changes in the main() function. Below is the code for this

```
import argparse
import cv2
import glob

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True, help= "Path to test dataset")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type = int, default = 128, help = 
"Threshold value")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


path_to_save = "D:/downloads/"

def main():
    i = 0
    for filename in glob.glob(args['dataset']):
        image = cv2.imread(filename)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (200, 200))
        ret, image = cv2.threshold(image, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imwrite(path_to_save + str(i) + '.jpg', image)
        i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you are familiar with glob, you must know how to give the Path to dataset argument. If not, then here is an example of how you should proceed:

-d "D:/downloads/*.*"    means grab all files (paths) in the specified folder

-d 'D:/downloads/*.jpg'  means grab only jpg files in the folder